# want to generate number through loop in multiple selector react native

Tags: react-native

[image]

hey guys I am using multiple selector in my app..the thing I want t show is that I want to generate num from 1 to 69 through loop..but when I tried to generate number by loop it gives me error like undefined is not a function ...

I tried a loop as globally and in my render function but every time I have same error...

```
 export default class Createottery extends Component {
   static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
   }
  state = { selectedFruits: [],mynum:[] }

  onSelectionsChange = (selectedFruits) => {
  //alert(JSON.stringify(selectedFruits))
// selectedFruits is array of { label, value }
this.setState({ selectedFruits:selectedFruits })
alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.selectedFruits))
 }
  componentDidMount(){
    for(let mylottery=0; mylottery<=69;mylottery++)
    {
        this.setState({mynum:mylottery})
            //alert(mylottery)
    }
      }
       render () {
  let comeon=0
  for(comeon=0;comeon<=5;comeon++){

comeon=comeon      }
return (
    <Container style={styles.Containerstyle}>
        <Header searchBar rounded style={styles.headerstyle}>
      <Item style={{backgroundColor:'#000'}}> 
        <Input placeholder="Lottery" placeholderttextSize={22} placeholderTextColor={'#fff'}/>
        <Icon name="search"  style={{color:'#fff'}} size={22}/>
      </Item>

    </Header>
<Content>
  <View >
      <Text style={{color:'#000',alignItems: 'center',fontSize:22}}>select any 5 number or quick pick</Text>
    <SelectMultiple
      style={{backgroundColor:'black'}}
     items={comeon}
      //selectedItems={this.state.selectedFruits}
     // onSelectionsChange={this.onSelectionsChange} 
      />
  </View>
</Content>
  </Container>
)
```

I want when my app starts It gives my all number which I want to generate through loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Because you are sending number to items of `SelectMultiple` Component. items should be array of object.

```
<SelectMultiple
    style={{backgroundColor:'black'}}
    items={comeon}   {//this should be array instead of number}
    selectedItems={this.state.selectedFruits}
    onSelectionsChange={this.onSelectionsChange} 
 />
```

2) You are doing the same mistake while creating array in componentDidMount. You are setting every looped number to `mynum`